# VBA Excel: Transfer to Word and Access

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a program in VBA excel that manipulates data and transfers it to a few different sheets.  What I would like to do now is transfer one sheet to Microsoft Access and one sheet to Microsoft Word.  I would like to keep all of the code in my excel VBA workbook if possible, as opposed to Access or Word.

I want the sheet named "Data" transferred to Word and "Points" transferred to Access.  I want the code to transfer these sheets to uncreated documents, then name the documents and save it.  Each sheet can be transferred individually.

I have tried looking up answers to this question but have failed to find any good information!  I have little idea where to begin with this specific code, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks for to much.  Books on Excel VBA like "Excel 2013 Power Programming with VBA (Mr. Spreadsheet's Bookshelf)" will help.

I will say that it will be easier for Access to pull the data from excel using it's own VBA code.  To send data to word int he way you describe, will involve initialising a new word application and a new document.

Get a book, it will pay for itself as this sort of situation is often described.

Try google searche for:

"linking to excel data in an access application"

Also see:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/698670-using-excel-visual-basic-applications-export-data-ms-access-table.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PhpZQw1ktP4

And Youtube channel ExcelisFun.

Harvey

Comment: Ok thanks, I don't currently have access to a book so I will rephrase my question on a simpler scale.  Mainly, I am trying to transfer a single sheet of Excel to Access.

Comment: See extra text in my answer - but still get a book